# Change variable that lives on the nodejs server from client side

Tags: node.js, variables, client

I have a question, lets say that i have a variable that lives on the nodejs server called:
Var optionOne = "Yes"

And i want to change that variable from the client side by a button press. How would i handle that?, because obviously document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", change) wont work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Node is just for server side, after you do something like this `document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", change)` you will need to send this information from the client to the server side.

like this

```
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(document.getElementById("myBtn").value);
```

Comment: Hey man, i am kinda stuck with this, is there anyway i could contact you so you could help me with this? @Welyngton Dal Prá

Answer (score 0):

You put a web service route into your server, then you hit it with .fetch or AJAX from the client.

Comment: Could you give me a more clear example, or maybe a link to the subject? @O.Jones